# Docker Compose Hostname DNS Lookup Fails

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, localhost

I have a simple Docker compose file as below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
     build: ./server
     networks:
        - common
     ports:
        - "4840:4840"
     container_name: open62541_server
     hostname: open62541-server
  client:
    build: ./client
    depends_on:
       - server
    container_name: open62541_client
    networks:
        - common

networks:
    common:
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Attaching to open62541_server, open62541_client
open62541_server | [2019-06-27 12:19:54.864 (UTC+0000)] info/network    TCP network layer listening on opc.tcp://open62541-server:4840/
open62541_client | [2019-06-27 12:19:55.590 (UTC+0000)] warn/network    DNS lookup of open62541-server failed with error Name or service not known
open62541_client exited with code 0
```

Even after specifying that the containers belong to a common network, why is that I get this error? Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `server` (service name) as host to which you connect within docker-compose network instead of `open62541-server` as neither container_name nor hostname section in docker file affects docker-compose's internal DNS.

Comment: (`hostname:` is also basically totally a no-op — it only affects what the container thinks its own hostname is and doesn’t affect any other container or DNS setup.  Docker Compose also provides a `default` network for you, and you should be able to successfully delete all of your `network:` blocks.)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a typo in the config file. `hostname` is `open62541-server` and `container_name` is `open62541_server` (with underscore). You should be able to connect to server with either the service name (i.e. `server`) or container_name (i.e. `open62541_server`)